# Spring boot app not work on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application with one controller returning string "hello world". I created docker image and I have difficulty in deploying it on AWS.

I created instance for my service , added security group and status is UP, but I can't ping my instance and access my controller.

May it be a problem with automatically added tomcat by spring boot ? I can run docker image locally and it starts on localhost

Comment: May you please add more information.

Comment: Error stack trace would be helpful. However I have a hunch: on linux ports below 1024 can be opened only by root, so try to run spring-boot project with `sudo`.

Comment: What exactly should I add ? I don't run my application manually. I only created docker image from my app and uploaded it to aws

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the port you're running on (default embedded Tomcat port is 8080)
2. Verify that when you run the Docker container, that you're publishing the container port on the host (e.g. docker run -p 8080:8080 myapp)
3. The security group port needs to match the host port you've published to (e.g. 8080)
4. The security group source needs to allow traffic from your IP address (allow traffic from anywhere with: 0.0.0.0/0)
5. Ensure you've bound the security to your EC2 instance.
6. Verify your app is running by checking the container logs (e.g. docker logs containerId)

Comment: Why I need to run command "docker run -p 8080:8080 myapp" if I uploaded my image to AWS ? If I do so, it would run my app locally

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing since not many specifics were included. For example, how are you running the docker container, ECS or by hand via EC2? How are you uploading your docker image, ECR or a local build on the same EC2 instance?  More detail will greatly help our answers.

Comment: I do everything according to this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/

Comment: Okay so you're using ECS. My guess would be a misconfigured load balancer. It depends if you're using classic or the new ALB.